# Histogram of random distribution

Tags: python, numpy, matplotlib, math, statistics

I don't know if this is a math-related question or a computer-related question so decided to ask on both sites.

First, I need to say that I don't have much knowledge in statistics and probability, so I think that might be the reason I'm asking these questions.

---

So I was playing around with matplotlib, plotting histograms of different distributions, and saw something weird in the random distribution created by numpy (`numpy.random.random`).

```py
data = np.random.random(1000)
plt.hist(data, bins = 100, density=True)
```

[image]

Here are my questions :

1. Why do some bars cross the limit of [0-1]? isn't density defined as written below?

> density = (number of occurrences of a data point / total number of data).

By that definition, no density should be more than 1 and less than 0. If so, why do some bars cross that limit? Have I misunderstood the meaning of density? Shouldn't the maximum density be less than 1?

---

```py
data = np.random.random(1000)
plt.hist(data, bins = 100)
```

[image]

2. If I turn `density=False`, I get the above result. The maximum occurrence of a bin, according to the plot, is about **20 times**. If I divide that by the length of my data array, 1000, it should be 0.02, but instead, with `density=True`, my max height is 2 and not 0.02. Why is that?

I think I might have misunderstood the definition of density, what it means, how it is calculated, and what it represents. So I'd really appreciate it if you could explain density in simple terms for me.

I think I also might have some wrong ideas about random distributions and think of them as normal distributions, which is why I'm struggling to understand this problem and figure it out. If you could also explain random distributions and their key differences with normal distributions, I'd really appreciate it.

Comment: With `density=True`, the total area will be 1 units.  As the total width of the blue area of the uniform distribution over 0-1 is 1 unit, the average height should also be 1 unit. To get the average to 1, some values will be higher and some will be lower.  With a standard normal distribution, the width is much higher, depending on the smallest and largest value that happens to be randomly chosen. The highest point of the normal distribution is about 0.4, making it quite unlikely that the density histogram would be higher than 1 somewhere.

Comment: density = (number of occurrences of a data point / total number of data) / Δx. This is why it is called "density", such that integral is equal to 1

Answer (score 1):

The description of the density parameter can be found in numpy's documentation here: https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.histogram.html

From the documentation:

> density : bool, optional
>
> If False, the result will contain the number of samples in each bin.
> If True, the result is the value of the probability density function
> at the bin, normalized such that the integral over the range is 1.
> Note that the sum of the histogram values will not be equal to 1
> unless bins of unity width are chosen; it is not a probability mass
> function.

Seeing as the goal is that the integral (note: integeral not sum) is 1, the average bar is of height 1, because a perfectly random distribution would be a rectangle from 0 to 1 on the x axis and 0 to 1 on the y axis and have an area of 1.

In other words, certain bars can be taller than 1 because the width of each bin is less than one, so each bar still has an area lower than 1.

Of course, because this is random, some bars have heights less than 1 and some bars have heights greater than 1.

Comment: so why doesn't the same thing happen with **normal distribution**? if I plot histogram of the density of a normal distribution, height of the bars won't pass 1 but if were to choose a random distribution, the height will pass 1. why is that?

Comment: @AmirMohammadShakeri No, with normal distribution it would be the same effect - you plot gaussian PDF, overlap it with sampled histogram and some bins would be above PDF curve, and some would be below

Comment: AmirMohammad Shakeri, whether or not your normal distribution's density's height passes 1 depends on its standard deviation. Try it with a low standard deviation. Plotting with density = True just means that total area = 1. A skinnier distribution will, therefore, be taller.

Comment: @tryna_learn
thanks, i appreciate you explaining it to me. i think i need to study a little probability and statistics in order to be able to understand what you mean completely.

Comment: You should accept the answer if it's answered your question.